# VBA Calculate percentage

Tags: excel, vba

So i need some help. Im pretty new to VBA so im having some trouble.
Well i have multiple sheets in my work book (excel). what im trying to do is, calculate the percentage of how many cells have the word "IMCOMPLETE" in column D and putting the outcome in the main sheet on a certain cell. Example:

```
Sub Get_Percentage()

If Range("Jackson,_Mr._Vince_R.TrainingSt'!D2:D100").Value = "IMCOMPLETE" Then
    put outcome in "TotalSummery%"!E2
If Range("Carter,_Mr._Oscar_R_(Oscar)Trai'!D2:D100").Value = "IMCOMPLETE" Then
    put outcome in "TotalSummery%"!E4
If Range("Taravella,_Mr._Jim_(Jim)Trainin'!D2:D100") Value = "IMCOMPLETE" Then
    put outcome in "TotalSummery%"!E5

End Sub
```

FYI: I have like 10 sheet tabs. Not sure if this would be a macro.

Comment: Please avoid things like "Please help" in your questions or subjects. And always avoid SHOUTING whenever possible (unless it's important like the use of `INCOMPLETE` is in your question). SHOUTING NEEDLESSLY simply makes text harder to read, and begging for help will not get it for you sooner. Everyone that asks a question here is equally important, and begging won't move you up on any priority list. Thanks.

Comment: A couple of hints, you need `End If`'s, instead of `put outcome` you need `Range("TotalSummery%"!E2).Value2 = "a value"`. To find how many cells have the imcomplete you can use   With .ActiveSheet
.Cells.Find(What:="IMCOMPLETE", After:=objExcel.ActiveCell, LookIn:=objExcel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt :=objExcel.XlLookAt.xlPart, SearchOrder:=objExcel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection:=objExcel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase:= False)

Comment: @Ken, sorry about that. Completely understand.

Comment: @JeremyThompson I get what your saying, but i cant get put it together. I keep getting errors. FYI Im really new at VBA.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindAndCountWordInExcelWorkBook(Byval SearchString As String)

SearchString = "IMCOMPLETE"

Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim FoundAt As String
    On Error GoTo Err
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count

        Set ws = Worksheets(i)
        Set oRange = ws.UsedRange

        Dim CountOfKeyWord As Integer

        Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            FoundAt = aCell.Address
            Do While ExitLoop = False
                Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    CountOfKeyWord = CountOfKeyWord + 1
                    FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
                Else
                    ExitLoop = True
                End If
            Loop
        Else
           ' MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
        End If

    Next i

    MsgBox "The Search String: " & SearchString & ", appeared " & CountOfKeyWord & " times at these locations: " & FoundAt
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it. I am doing it for one sheet. You can use it in a loop

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim WordCount As Long, ColDTotalWordCount As Long
    Dim PercentageWord As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    SearchText = "IMCOMPLETE"

    With ws
        '~~> Count the occurances of the word "IMCOMPLETE"
        WordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(4), SearchText)

        '~~> Count the total words in Col D
        ColDTotalWordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(4))

        '~~> Calculate Percentage
        PercentageWord = WordCount / ColDTotalWordCount
        Debug.Print Format(PercentageWord, "00.00%")
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code can be also converted to a function which can be very useful when you are looping through the sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TextToSearch  As String

    Set wSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    TextToSearch = "IMCOMPLETE"

    Debug.Print GetPercentage(wSheet, TextToSearch)
End Sub

Function GetPercentage(ws As Worksheet, SearchText As String) As String
    Dim WordCount As Long, ColDTotalWordCount As Long
    Dim PercentageWord As Double

    With ws
        '~~> Count the occurances of the word "IMCOMPLETE"
        WordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(4), SearchText)

        '~~> Count the total words in Col D
        ColDTotalWordCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(4))

        '~~> Calculate Percentage
        PercentageWord = WordCount / ColDTotalWordCount
        GetPercentage = Format(PercentageWord, "00.00%")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: ok looks like this code will get the data, but how would it know where to put it? The outcome cells are not all alined. They are in the same column but not one after the other.

Comment: `but how would it know where to put it?`: Er, you will tell it?